# XSD: required nested tags if optional parent exists

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, nested

I have tags which are optional in my XML, if the optional tag is present I then need the child tags of that element to be required, how can I achieve this using XSD (or another solution if this is not possible in XSD)?

An example part of my XML:

```
                <xs:element name="deviceLocation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="xPos"/>
                      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="yPos"/>
                      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="zPos"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
```

As you can see the `deviceLocation` tag is optional - if this tags exists I then want the child tags `xPos`, `yPos` and `zPos` to be required.

EDIT: Full schema as requested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="homeML">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="inhabitantDetails" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="inhabitantID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="carePlan" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="comment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
          </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="location" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="locationID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="locationDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="referenceObjects" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="locationDevice" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="lDeviceID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
                    <xs:element name="deviceDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
                    <xs:element name="deviceLocation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="xPos" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="yPos" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="zPos" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="units" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
                    <xs:element name="realTimeInformation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="runID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="sampleRate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="startTimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="endTimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="event" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="lEventID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="timeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="mobileDevice" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="mDeviceID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="deviceDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="units" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="devicePlacement" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="quantisationResolution" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="realTimeInformation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="runID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="sampleRate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="startTimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="endTimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="event" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="mEventID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="timeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="support" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="annotationDetails" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="annotationID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              <xs:element name="experimentType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              <xs:element name="lDevice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="mDevice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
              <xs:element name="startTimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              <xs:element name="endTimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a (child) element like this:

```
<xs:element name="n" minOccurs="0" type="someType"/>
```

then the element is optional, but if it occurs, then it must conform to the type someType. So if someType defines a content model with mandatory elements, then n is optional, but when present, the children of n are mandatory.

By the way, it's elements that are optional, not tags. An element typically has two tags, a start tag and an end tag.

Comment: Can I just confirm that it is indeed `<xsl:element.../>` instead of `<xsd:element.../>`? I always understood XSL to be a completely seperate tool from XSD.

Comment: Sorry, yes, my fingers type "xsl:" automatically. Will correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help, just to clarify when you say `type="someType"` do you mean simply types such as `type="xs:string"` or do you mean a user defined type?

Comment: I've implemented this but it still allows me to have the `xs:element name="deviceLocation"` without the position elements even though they should be required if the `xs:element name="deviceLocation"` is present.

Comment: In your case, someType would be a user-defined type. Of course, it could also be an anonymous type defined inline. I don't know why it's not working for you: show us your full schema and tell us which XSD processor you are using.

Comment: Full schema put in original post, as for the XSD processor I'm currently just testing it in an online validator - could this be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Your elements xPos, yPos, and zPos are declared with minOccurs="0", which means they are optional. If you want them mandatory, use minOccurs="1".

Comment: ahh it's always the little things! That works perfectly now, thank you very much for your help!